# Is there a concept in any language of an equality ternary operator that checks for equality and returns either a side of the check or a default value

Tags: python, ruby, kotlin, groovy, language-agnostic

From time to time I need to do some evaluation like this:

```
someVar == "something" ? "something" : "someOther"
```

*please note that == is doing an equality check and not an assignment*

Now I wonder if there is any concept in any language that makes this expression more compact like

```
someVar ?== "something" : "someOther"
```

Do you know of a language that offers such a feature and if yes, how this concept is called?

*edit:*
Since some answers already suggested the ternary or elvis operator, this is not what I'm searching. I look for a concept that does essentially an equality check as the condition of the ternary operator and returns either one side of this check or a default value.

*edit2:*
I'd like to emphasize again, that I'm not interested in solutions how you can achieve something like that by implementing it yourself. That's obviously not a hard thing to do, but I'm interested if such an operation exists in any language and if there's a term for it.

And also note that I don't want to discuss whether or not this operation would make sense or should be part of a language.

Comment: Can you give a real-world example for this use case?

Comment: In Kotlin you could use `someVar.takeIf { it == "something" } ?: "someOther"`, but there is no single operator for this...

Comment: I just had it in my build pipeline: `build(platform, (appType == "appstore" ? "appstore" : "build"))`. The build function takes two arguments, a _platform_ and a _task_. Now, by convention in this case the _task_ has the same name as the apptype, so this shorthand would be handy to use here.

Comment: I had to read this a few times before I noticed the `==` was not a `=` in your first example. That might be why everyone's suggesting Elvis or null-coalescing. Might help to put parentheses around `someVar == "something"`.

Comment: To me the concept is like [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) which can be implemented with a [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) for most programming languages. If the language has [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) then a preprocessor should not be needed which is dynmaiclly handled. Prolog also has [term expansion](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=progtransform) which is done before compilation.

Comment: Since the answer to your question is “no”, it makes sense to discuss why it shouldn’t be a first-class part of a language, rather than having to explicitly reference the docs of hundreds of programming languages to exhaustively *prove* it doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most concise way I can think of writing it in `ruby`:

```rb
someVar = "someOther" unless someVar == "something"
```

...So no, not as a single operator.

Comment: This is the only thing that makes sense. I can't see a reason to add another special operator (per OP's question) for this kind of check; there's a couple other ways to do this with hash merging (if it was data in a hash) and whatnot as well.

Comment: The question is about an *expression*, not an *assignment*

Comment: @claasz Ah... The [pre-edited wording in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59685357/revisions) did not make this entirely clear: *"I wonder if there is any concept in any language that makes this assignment more compact"*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this particular case is common enough for any language to have a dedicated operator for it. In your example in the comment on the original question (quoted below), it's an arbitrary design decision or serendipity that one of the possible `appType`s is the same as one of the two possible tasks and corresponds *exclusively* with it.

> I just had it in my build pipeline: `build(platform, (appType == "appstore" ? "appstore" : "build"))`. The build function takes two arguments, a platform and a task. Now, by convention in this case the task has the same name as the apptype, so this shorthand would be handy to use here.

Of course, if your particular project uses this a lot, a simple function can be written to simplify it, and some languages let you overload operators so you could get a usage similar to your pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat possible in Scala, since it allows overloading any operator. The only problem is that semicolon is reserved in Scala.

```
val someVar  = new Questioner("something")
println("Start " + someVar)

someVar ?== "something" `:` "someOther"

println(someVar) // something

someVar ?== "someOther" `:` "something"

println(someVar) // someOther
```

And that's the actual code:

```
case class Questioner[T](private var value: Semicoloner[T]) {

  def `?==`(other: Semicoloner[T]) {
    if (this.value.value != other.other) {
      this.value = new Semicoloner(other.other)
    }
  }

  override def toString = this.value.value.toString
}

case class Semicoloner[T](val value: T, val other : T) {
  def `:`(other: Semicoloner[T]): Semicoloner[T] = {
    return new Semicoloner(this.value, other.value)
  }

  def this(value : T) {
    this(value, value) 
  }
}


implicit def anythingToSemicoloner[T](a : T) : Semicoloner[T] = {
  new Semicoloner(a)
}
```

Probably could go with something even crazier, but I'll stop here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but I'm not interested in how you can do this on your own, but if this exists as an operator in any language and how its called. I edited my question to emphasize that again.

Answer (score -1):

In `python` is more verbose, the syntax is this:

```py
a if condition else b
```

An example:

```
def get_bigger(a, b):
    return a if a > b else b
```

Comment: This is just the ternary operator. I'm looking for an operator that does an equality check as the `condition` and returns either one side of this equality check or `b`